# Modelo de base de datos (ingreso y registro al sistema)

Tags: base-de-datos

Evaluacion por ejemplo es como una materia del colegio, matematicas fisica quimica.

Intentos por ejemplo son los examenes que se dan para cada materia

**Quiero saber los intentos de un usuario respecto a una evaluacion**

El id_usuario debe estar en la entidad Intento?

Adjunto el modelo relacional

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seria interesante saber de que trata la base de datos a que negocio ira, asi se podria generar una mejor ayuda.

Comment: Que mas amigo, la idea seria que antes de poner el modelo de clases ese que pones allí, para tener mas ideas, y no poner así separado, si no algo así, *intento crear un modelo de base de datos el cual consiste en un modelo de base de datos para una entidad que vende autos y un par de cosas mas agrega si necesitas*

Comment: la pregunta repite 3 veces lo mismo, y no es nada clara. No entiendo ninguno de los votos positivos.

Comment: Yo sigo sin entenderla.. que son intentos? de que? una evaluacion de que? deberias explicar que es tu modelo y un poco mas de contexto, para saber de que estas hablando... antes de darle una recompensa, yo hubiera pensado en explicar mejor tu problema.

Comment: @gbianchi ahora ya esta mas claro,

Comment: Ponele que si.. igual era tan facil de explicar como: se quiere saber cuantas veces un alumno hizo tal examen, ya que si lo reprueba lo tiene que volver a hacer. Mas alla de eso, la entidad intento no tiene sentido de ser.. no alcanza con que este todo en la entidad evaluacion?

Comment: @gbianchi es que cada evaluacion tiene examenes, en realidad intento es como la nota de cada examen de una evaluacion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Que tipo de relación encontramos acá?

Si cada alumno puede hacer la evaluacion varias veces (intentos), entonces tenemos una relación 1 a N entre alumnos e intentos.

Por lo tanto, en ese caso el id_alumno va en la tabla intentos.

Ya que no hay forma de que varios alumnos hagan el mismo intento (pero si la misma evaluacion), entonces podemos asegurar la relacion 1 a N.

En ese grafico que mostras, sin embargo, hay muchas relaciones que no se entienden.

Se supone que una evaluacion es unica, y no esta relacionada con ningun alumno. Podria estar relacionada con una materia. Por lo tanto, hay relaciones ilogicas dentro de lo que mostras.

### ***NOTA IMPORTANTE***

Es importante entender, que las relaciones en una base de datos, estan dadas por las reglas del negocio. No hay una unica forma de hacer las relaciones sin saber con precision las reglas que tiene ese negocio. Uno puede suponer como deberia ser, pero sin saber si por ejemplo, el alumno puede hacer mas de un intento, es imposible saber si efectivamente el modelo es correcto o no.

Comment: un alumno puede hacer muchas veces una evaluacion

Comment: eso lo conteste. que otra duda te quedo @hubman?

Comment: pero la relacion de que un usuario pertenece a una evaluacion estaria bien? entidades: usuario, pertenece, evaluacion

Comment: por lo que dijiste el intento, lo hace un usuario. la evaluacion no tiene nada que ver con los usuarios. Las evaluaciones son de las materias (usando un concepto de alumno materia, la evaluacion es de la materia)

Answer (score 4):

¿**El id_usuario debe estar en la entidad Intento?** Mi respuesta es sí.

Un *usuario* tiene varios *intentos* y cada *intento* pertenece a un *usuario*.
Así mismo, cada *intento* pertenece a una *evaluación* y las evaluaciones pueden ser intentadas varias veces.

> [usuario]-1-N->[intento]<-N-1-[evaluacion]

Por eso, el intento debe contener la *id_usuario* y la *id de la evaluación* a la que pertenece.

Por lo anterior, la evaluación no debería tener otra relación con el usuario, el "intento" es el único intermediario que se necesita entre ambas. Te aconsejo tratar de evitar cualquier tipo de relación circular o podrías tener varios problemas al implementarlas.

Otra cosa a considerar son los tipos de los atributos. Si la id_evaluacion es tipo "serial" debería reflejarse de la misma manera en la tabla "intento", lo mismo para el id_usuario.